# How to Reimport a Certificate to Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure-keyvault

How can I reimport an SSL certificate in place of an expiring certificate in Azure Key Vault? I can't find the relevant API in the Key Vault docs (except for the original Import API).

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/importcertificate/importcertificate).

Comment: That's the import API. What happens when I get a renewed version of the cert from my CA? How do I import the new one as a new version of the old one?

Comment: Perhaps, you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/updatecertificate/updatecertificate) to update your certificate.

Comment: Thanks, but the update API does not seem to update the certificate and key files themselves. only metadata/polices about the certificate? How do I replace one certificate with a new one (new version) that I want to import in place of it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, If you want to reimport a new version SSL certificate in place of an expiring certificate in Azure Key Vault. You can directly import a new certificate to your Azure key vault. Once the import is final, subsequent operations will use the new policy (new versions). Refer to [Import a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificate-scenarios#import-a-certificate). You could also get more details from this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates/).

Also, you can import a new version certificate from your Key Vault---Certificates---the old certificate---New Version---Import, on the Azure Portal.

[image]